# GIS: partition area based on equal population

Tags: gis, postgis, arcgis, qgis

I want to partition a US state into 20 parts of approximately equal population. I can do this using, say, tracts, ZIP codes or another smaller geography. I'm looking for an algorithm to do the partitioning. It can be in any language or software (ArcGIS, QGIS, python, PostGIS, R, node).

For grouping or clustering algorithms I've looked at like k-means, ArcGIS Grouping Analysis, etc. These do not seem to do what's needed, since they group based on the **similarity** of a variable don't partition into equal size based on a variable. My quick look at [ESRI's districting tool](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/districting/download) suggests that this might be a possibility.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you're asking "Is this already implemented in a neatly bundled package for me?" then it's not really about programming. Perhaps it belongs on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: If by "neatly packaged bundle" you mean a Python module or an R function or SQL code I could use in PostGIS then yes this is what I'm asking for. All of these would involve programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the [Shortest splitline algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering#Shortest_splitline_algorithm), recommended for creating [optimally compact](http://bdistricting.com/about.html#compact) voting districts. Here is [a description](http://rangevoting.org/GerryExamples.html) of its results in solving gerrymandering.

Comment: This looks good but do you know if it has been implemented anywhere?

Comment: According to RangeVoting's site http://rangevoting.org/SplitLR.html an implementation is http://autodistrict.cvs.sourceforge.net/autodistrict/

Comment: @jwd630:How is all possible lines defined? It seems very complicated. In kd-tree its a rectangle?

Comment: @ZRoss:I think a weighted voronoi diagram is better.

Comment: It depends on @ZRoss's unstated purpose. If that is to arrive at a partitioning where voronoi diagram properties excel then perhaps that is the best choice. If he wants something not as exact but simpler to explain to his audience perhaps something else.

Since he stated he wanted "20 parts of approximately equal" population and mentioned he was looking at districting tools I presumed something designed for defining political district boundaries - where the need to explain the rationale for where the lines are drawn to non-GIS specialists may be a key decision factor - might be best.

Comment: The http://autodistrict.cvs.sourceforge.net/autodistrict link is down. Is there another place to obtain this software?

Comment: If it is "fair and compact" electoral district software you are looking for then  [Auto-Redistrict](http://autoredistrict.org/) might be an alternative. Sourceforge appears to be having some [network difficulties](https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/969377360129773568).

Answer (score 1):

You can try centroidal weighted voronoi diagrams. i.e. Loyds algorithm. Pick the voronoi diagram and the center of gravity of each voronoi cell and rinse and repeat:http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/
[image]

Comment: Similar question I asked of jwd630, has this been implemented somewhere?

Comment: @ZRoss:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it! Thank you!