# Voronoi diagram of point clusters?

Tags: python, c++, sql, postgis, voronoi

Is there a way to compute the voronoi diagram of groups of points?

I.e. all points with the same label/value should be entirely contained by one voronoi segment. 
Computing the centroid of each group and using that for a regular voronoi diagram will not guarantee that points of the same group are contained within the same segment.

Calculating the convex hull of each group is also not satisfactory as it does not guarantee that either all segments are joined, or that segments do not overlap.

I am trying to derive approximate postal-code boundaries based on lat/long information for individual addresses.

The data itself is in postgis, but any language is suitable (extra points for solutions using sql, python or C++)...

Comment: metaphorical points. :)

Comment: [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) partitions a data set into Voronoi cells. Libs exist in many languages, including Python and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want a weighted voronoi diagram. The weights are subtracted from the euclidean distance.  IMO it also guarantee that the same points is in the same cell. You can check this question about equal size partition on population:[GIS: partition area based on equal population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892337/gis-partition-area-based-on-equal-population/27893356#27893356).